# How do I get Entity Framework 4 and WCF Data Services to work with Silverlight 3.0

Tags: silverlight-3.0, entity-framework-4, wcf-data-services

I have a project that needs to be upgraded in stages. I need to implement Entity Framework v4 first and then eventually upgrade the Silverlight v3 application to v4.

Unfortunately my client is not able to roll out Silverlight version 4 until for at least four months  (they do want to move to v4 but they have to go though a company wide upgrade program).

Anyway, My question is how do I get WCF Data Service to work with Silverlight 3 (as its not able to resolve DataServiceCollection or DataServiceQueryContinuation  ?

Or, what suggested workflow should I use to get WCF Data Service / Entity Framework v4 to work with Silverlight 3?

Thanks for your help in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You can either use the version of WCF Data Services which is part of Silverlight 3 with which you won't get data binding support and other perks. But it will work against the newer server just fine (assuming your server won't use any of the new features of course).
Or you can download this CTP: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/astoriateam/archive/2010/02/24/ado-net-data-services-for-silverlight-3-update-ctp3-now-available-for-download.aspx
It brings the V2 features to SL 3 as well.

Comment: Thanks very much for your response. I was hoping to use the CTP solution, but I have VS2010 -and it wont allow the Silverlight 3 tools. I did try just referencing those libraries directly in my Silverlight 3 project but that didnt work. Please could you elaborate on your first suggestion? Would I be better off creating a data layer and putting all the entity framework stuff in there and then referencing it via a WCF Service? -I just feel that it would be a waste of work as it will only need to be changed later on! -or am I missing something between what WCF Service & WCF Data Service can do?

Comment: If you're using VS2010, how do you build the SL3 project then? Note that you can use the command-line datasvcutil.exe to generate the client side proxy instead of VS.
Usually you have an EF model, which on the middle tier you expose through WCF Data Services, which is then consumed by the client.
As long as the WCF Data Services layer won't use any of the V2 features, the client can use the V1 library which shipped with SL3.